# Issue with wix installer upgrade from net472 to net6.0-windows app

Tags: wix

We have migrated our app from net472 to net6.0-windows. There is a wix installer for the app.
Currently the installer's upgrade sequence from net472 to net6.0-windows doesn't work as expected.

This is because there is a bunch of third party libs which have have the same file version for different platforms in net472 and net6.0-windows. e.g. NLog.dll would be 4.7.7.12472 in both platforms.

AFAIU, the file replacement rules work so that when source file(assembly in installer) and target file(installed assembly) version are equal, the installer will not replace this file.

So now after the upgrade, the bin folder is left with a mix of old(net472 from 3rd parties) and new(mostly our 'file version incremented' net6.0-windows) assemblies.

Any recommendations on how to solve this upgrade problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of broken component rules (by third parties).  The windows installer thinks it's good because the versions are the same but the files are not forward or backwards compatible.

Unless you want to set the REINSTALLMODE property to amus (forced overwrite of everything ) or do file by file version lying (file version attribe 65535.65535.65535.65535 to force that file to always overwrite ) you will need to do a MajorUpgrde scheduled afterInstallValidate.

Other possibilities is to treat this as a new product and install to a new directory or consider alternate .NET compile/publish options so that the app self contains those files without the installer ever seeing them.

Comment: like so? <MajorUpgrade AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" Schedule="afterInstallValidate" ...

Comment: That *should* do it. (From memory, not tested).  If not, you can also try changing the installation directory.

Comment: what is the difference between afterInstallValidate and afterInstallInitialize? in my setup afterInstallInitialize also seems to work. Would there be a scenario where the usage of afterInstallValidate is better?

Comment: ok just read the docs.  afterInstallInitialize is better because if the setup fails, a rollback occurs so that the system is still left with a running app once the setup completes.

Comment: There's pro's and con's of each not that one is better or worse.  Regardless fully test your scenarios.  WiX has a custom action available called WiXFailWhenDeferred that can simulate a failure and trigger a rollback.  Use this to do your install, repair, uninstall, reinstall, upgrade testing.